# Last logon script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to know how can I check the last login in my domain.
I need to know how many days the user isn't logged in (Some variable that will be like a counter).
for example, CSV file that will be with this variables:

```
USER- XXX 
Last Log in- DATA  
days logoff- **counter.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are not a coding-service. Please take a look at [tour], [ask] and offer an [mcve] of what you tried so far and where it failed.
You can edit your question to supply more informations.

Also take a look at `Get-Aduser` and `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`LastLogonTimestamp`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/) attribute?

Answer (score 0):

As a small base script to start with you could use something like this:

```
$lastlogon = @()
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property LastLogonTimestamp | Select SamAccountName,LastLogonTimestamp | Foreach($_) { 
    $item = New-Object System.Object
    $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Username -value $_.SamAccountName
    $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name LastLogon -value $([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp))
    $diff = New-TimeSpan -Start ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)) -End $(Get-Date) 
    $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name DaysSince -value $diff.Days
    $lastlogon += $item
}
$lastlogon | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\LastLogon.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

This will get the LastLogonTimestamp attribute of **all** your domain users, convert it to a more human readable format and then write it to the CSV file C:\Temp\LastLogon.csv you could open with e.g. Excel.
Additionally it computes the difference between *now* and the `LastLogonTimestamp` and writes it to the column `DaysSince` using the `New-TimeSpan' cmdlet.

You may want to narrow your search down by having a look at `Get-AdUser -Filter` or `-SearchBase`.

Please be aware that there might be strange time values for users that never logged in, because this script does not check for valid or invalid timestamps.

Comment: Creating a new object and then populating it makes this answer more confusing than it has to be.